# How to know the `status of my API call` when its `success'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, active-rest-client

I want to know the `status of my API call` when its `success`.

```
begin
  @project = Project.find( id: '22', authorization: @auth )
rescue ActiveRestClient::HTTPClientException, ActiveRestClient::HTTPServerException => e
  Rails.logger.error("Project find returned #{e.status} #{e.message}")
end
```

When my API fails to get a `project` with an id `'22'`, i get the `status` and the message as exception. But how can i get the `status 200` when its a `success` call.

Comment: you need to add your exception api response  to the ques. which API u r using?

Comment: https://github.com/whichdigital/active-rest-client

Comment: okay... whats the issue with `e.status`? it should return `200` on success

Comment: How would it return, i guess it catches exceptions... not success calls.

Comment: yeah u r right, in case you don't encounter an exception, you can try `@project.status`

Comment: I tried, i get undefined method status.

Comment: Why do you need to know the status? If there is no exception then you know it's a 20x or 304 response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From memory, you can access the HTTP status of a response object using simply:

```
@project._status
```

https://github.com/whichdigital/active-rest-client/blob/master/lib/active_rest_client/base.rb#L10

I was the main author of this project, although I no longer work for Which so am not really responsible for its future direction.  Feel free to ask any other questions.